# Wordpress image slider not working

Tags: php, wordpress, image, bxslider

Php image slider not working and I need help. The website is www.cherwellwindows.co.uk and the line of code that is not working is  Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide the line of code .. and be specific

Comment: We'd also appreciate a better explanation of "Not working"

Comment: Try to check console as well.

Comment: <img src="?php the_sub_field('slider_image'); ?" width="1170" height=""/>

Comment: The images are not displaying in the image slider, just a contineous loading circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inspected your slider and found that the source of image is not properly displayed through code.

Please see the attachment : [Attachment](http://prntscr.com/fbyiib)

If your image is displayed then kindly, the slider should work.

Your code:

```
<?php 
if( have_rows('slides') ): ?> 
<div class="row slider-container"> 
    <ul class="bxslider"> 
    <?php while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row(); ?> 
        <li> 
            <img src="?php the_sub_field('slider_image'); ?" width="1170" height=""/> 
             <?php if( get_sub_field('slider_title') || get_sub_field('slider_paragraph') ): ?>
```

You have mistake in

SO,
working code will be:

```
<?php 
if( have_rows('slides') ): ?> 
<div class="row slider-container"> 
    <ul class="bxslider"> 
    <?php while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row(); ?> 
        <li> 
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('slider_image'); ?>" width="1170" height=""/> 
             <?php if( get_sub_field('slider_title') || get_sub_field('slider_paragraph') ): ?>
```

Hope it will work now

Thank You

Comment: Is the source of the image not the slider image code: ('slider_image')?

Comment: The value should be displayed here but in your element its showing the PHP code.

Comment: The line of code was working this morning but then it stopped working. This was the line I copied this morning which was working. img src="<?php the_sub_field('slider_image'); ?

Comment: can you show me the code so that we can debug it ?

Comment: <?php if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>
        <div class="row slider-container">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <?php while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <li>
<img src="?php the_sub_field('slider_image'); ?" width="1170" height=""/>
                        <?php if( get_sub_field('slider_title') || get_sub_field('slider_paragraph') ): ?>

Comment: I think its not full code. could you please provide us the full code?

Comment: See my edited answer so that you find your answer why its not working for you

Comment: If I copy and paste that code in, will it start working again?

Comment: Now, it should work for you ... u have missing < before ? while starting the code.

Comment: That worked fine thank. Can I ask you to look at one further bit of code or do I need to start a new question?

Comment: @MattSmith we can talk in gmail or in linkedin if you want

Comment: Great how do we talk in gmail?

Comment: connect with me aliashiquemohamad@gmail.com

Comment: could you mark my answer as correct one ?

Comment: THank You, will you send me email on my account ?

Comment: I sent you an email but got a bounce back?

Comment: @MattSmith do you have facebook?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/aliashiquemohammad

Comment: see you there :)